Xournal++ how to delete text everywhere in document?
How can I delete a given phrase, say "the quick brown fox", from every page in a PDF? It's >500 pages so I'd rather not remove just every instance manually.
I'd be OK with whiteout but would much rather delete the text as text.
The text appears in the same place on almost every page

If I read this section of the manual correctly, Xournal++ offers no feature for changing in any way. As far as I understand the PDF file format, adding text is rather simple, manipulating text consistently however is not.
There are some tools out there which offer bulk text-and-replace features:

pdf-redactor
borb
pypdf_strreplace (Disclaimer: I am the author of pypdf_strreplace)

All these tools are pretty limited. YMMV.
For accurate results, you probably need to get one of the "big guns":

Adobe Pro
https://code-industry.net/masterpdfeditor/
https://www.qoppa.com/pdfstudio/

This list is not exhaustive.
